# Is $\sin ^{2}\left ( x-y \right )$ metric space?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, metric-spaces

I am supposed to determine if $x,y\in \mathbb{R}$,

> $d\left ( x,y \right )=\sin ^{2} \left ( x-y \right )$

is metric space. The first and the second conditions are easy, but how do I show the triangle inequality?

Comment: $\sin^2(x) = (x - y)$ does not make sense to me. What do you mean?

Comment: @Jan sorry, I made a typo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$d(x, y) = \sin^2(x - y)$ does not define a metric. Note that $d(x, y) = 0$ implies $x - y = k \pi$ for a $k \in \mathbb{Z}$, but you necessarily need $x = y$ in this case.

Comment: oh okay, thank you